# Имена в "Руслане и Людмиле"

Tags: этимология, ономастика, пушкин

Меня интересует вот что: имена, упомянутые Пушкиным в "Руслане и Людмиле", — вымышленные или реальные древнерусские имена?
Насколько я знаю, имя Людмила действительно было, а что насчет остальных:
Руслан, Рогдай, Ратмир, Наина?
Если реальные, что они означают (понятно только с Ратмиром и наполовину с Русланом)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что касается **Руслана**. Пушкин черпал вдохновение, вероятно, из «Повести о Еруслане Лазаревиче», а это устный вариант тюркского дастана о богатыре Рустаме по прозвищу Арслан (Лев). У Пушкина Руслан вероятно кипчак-половец. То есть имя Руслан по происхождению тюркское. Об этом говорится во многих источниках.

Происхождение и значение имени **Рогдай** затемнено. В летописи оно встречается лишь единожды (Новгородская летопись), значение имени Рогдай в отличие от других древнерусских имен не вычленяется при анализе (на фоне Ярополк, Святополк, Святослав и т.д). Но вот вам еще два имени, скандинавские по происхождению: **Рог**волод и **Рог**неда. Связи с русским существительным *рог* нет.

Имя **Ратмир** славянское. Означает оно «ратующий за мир», «защитник мира», «воин мира», «войско мира». Также существует вариант перевода – «ратник». При этом у Пушкина Ратмир - "младой *хазарский* князь". У сербов есть женский вариант имени – Ратимирка. 
Имя Ратмир (Ратша) носил реальный исторический персонаж - новгородский богатырь XIII века, соратник князя Александра Ярославича Невского. Имя этого богатыря упоминается в числе шести главных героев Невской битвы в летописи «Повести о житии Александра Невского». В летописи сказано, что он погиб во время боя, но некоторые исследователи утверждали, что он выжил и в дальнейшем служил брату Невского – князю Ярославу Ярославовичу. Возможно, что одно и то же имя носили несколько богатырей. Ратмир был символом новгородского величия, особо почитаемым героем. Его меч хранился новгородцами и передавался из поколения в поколение. Наиболее известен эпизод, когда этот меч был вручен молодому полководцу Мирославу, зятю Марфы Посадницы, для обороны Новгорода от московского князя Ивана Великого.

Имя **Наина** по происхождению древнееврейское, означает "невинная" (об этом говорится во многих источниках). Учитывая исторические обстоятельства поэмы, можно предположить, что Наина - хазарка (ИМХО).

Comment: Хазарка в Финляндии? Откуда?

Answer (score 2):

Чувство юмора поэта Пушкина безгранично: хотя имени Наина в финском языке нет, но слово ***наина*** (naina) есть и означает *замужнюю* или *познавшую мужчину женщину*.

Comment: Говорят, что Пушкин просто не знал значения и воспринял как имя собственное.

Answer (score 1):

С Наиной какая-то непонятка. Я не буду полемизировать, приведу только версии.
~1. Наина - производное от финского «nainen» — женщина. Правдоподобно.
~2. Наина - еврейское имя. Точных данных не имею. Во всяком случае в современном иврите не встречается.
~3. Наина - имя украинское. Не сталкивался.
~4. Наина - испорченное Фаина или Наиля. Крайне сомнительно.
~5. Наина - русское нецерковное имя, ныне утраченное. Версия вполне правдоподобная.   Учитывая то, что все имена у Пушкина - славянские, славянизированные или вымышленные стилизованные, версия представляется едва ли не самой правдоподобной.

Руслан - славянизированное имя иранского (никак не тюркского!) происходения, в большой чести у осетин (ср. Сослан, Беслан и просто Алан). В основе общеиранское Алан (Арьян) - божественный, благородный.
По турецки лев - аслан, но трансформация в Руслан вряд ли была бы возможна.

Людмила - псевдославянское имя, популярное благодаря Жуковскому.

Рогдай - вероятно славянизированное имя скандинавского происхождения. По другой версии - родственно полоцким именам, но сомнительно.

Фарлаф - самое непонятное из всех, скорее всего умышленно оставлено Пушкиным "неопознанным". Возможно составлено из имен Фарлов и Флелаф, известных по договору Олега с греками (911 г.). Эти имена безусловно скандинавского происхождения, но сама версия весьма недостоверна.

Остальное - уже сказано.

(+)====
@grizzly

> А. Л. Слонимский считал, что происхождение этого имени не вызывает
> сомнений:

Я разделяю мнение (отнюдь не только Слонимского), что Фарлаф - производное (см. выше), но уверять, что оно не вызывает сомнений... Полагаю, это трактовка grizzly, а не Слонимского. Ибо есть масса других объяснений, от искаженного греческого Харлампий до норманского Олафа, а то и реального нормана, якобы носившего имя Фарлаф. Вся беда в том, что все эти версии одинаково недостоверны.

> Людмила. Старинное славянское — "милая людям". В "святцы" проникло как
> имя чешской княгини (922 г.), но признано у русских не было до XX
> века.

Голословно. Чтобы уверять в древности имени необходимо привести хоть какой-то список носителей. В отношении св. Людмилы Чешской (как аргумента о древности)  есть один каверзный вопрос. Каково было её крестное имя? Крестить Людмилой её не могли, ибо до неё святых с таким именем не было. Могу лишь предположить, что это имя на самом деле прозвище. Подобное тому как христианское имя      св. Владимира - Василий, а прозвища он имел - Красно Солнышко, Креститель и несколько еще. Или, что не менее вероятно Людмила калька с греческого. Подобно тому, как "переведены" были именя Вера, Надежда и Любовь.
Разумеется, мнение всех, кто задает испытывает сомнения, grizzly может не интересовать, но таки интересно, как же её звали-то на саом деле...

(++) =======

@grizzly

> **Зачем читать, что написал Слонимский?**

А вы все-таки прочтите тот текст на который ссылаетесь.
По вашей ссылке читаем:

> Эта историческая тенденция сказывается и в подборе имен действующих
> лиц у Пушкина. В частности, имя Фарлафа ***несомненно*** заимствовано из
> договора Олега с греками (911 г.), помещенного в летописи Нестора. В
> числе послов Олега двое носят имена, сходные с именем пушкинского
> героя: Фарлов и Флелаф. Из этих двух имен, ***повидимому***, и составлено
> имя „Фарлаф“. Так как история Карамзина, где напечатан этот договор
> (т. I, гл. V), вышла только в 1818 г., а Фарлаф у Пушкина фигурирует
> уже в первой песне, написанной раньше, то следует предположить, что
> имя Фарлафа взято ***непосредственно*** из летописи.2

http://feb-web.ru/feb/pushkin/serial/v37/v372183-.htm

Курсив мой (b-s) орфография автора.

Даже для самого автора несомненен только греческий источник. В отношении же якобы собственной версии он употребляет "по-видимому". И при этом дальше сам же себя и опровергает, уверяя читателя, что имя взято ***непосредственно*** из летописи. Полагаю, что источник вообще основан нам каких-то черновых, непроработанных  материалах... Дело не в орфографии, конечно, а в непричесанности мысли...

А вы говорите "зачем читать" источник. Вот для этого...

Comment: Зачем читать, что написал Слонимский? Даже если уже готовую цитату принесли на блюдечке. Намного проще во всех своих проблемах огульно обвинять оппонентов. Я выделил в своём ответе непонятое Вами место. Тратить время на споры подобного уровня? Увольте.

Comment: grizzly *Зачем читать, что написал Слонимский?* Вы серьезно? То есть я должен читать ваши "выделения" - и искать в них логику? Нет, увольте, отсылая к старому одесскому анекдоту, я хочу слушать Карузо, а не то, как его Рабинович по телефону напел.

Comment: ПС Я правильно понял, вы приписал Слонимскому те слова, которых он никогда не говорил? О том, что **эта версия не вызывает сомнений**?  Н-да...

Answer (score 0):

Имена реальные. Например, жену нашего бывшего президента, Ельцина, звали как раз Наина.

Comment: Это ничего не значит. Ее могли назвать в честь пушкинской героини.

Comment: Ну, сложно сказать. Все имена откуда-то берутся =) Реальность имени ведь как определить? Главное, чтобы не было уродств вроде называния мальчика Энекимомскайуокером (слитно) или Агитпро́п (бр-р-р, жуть).

Answer (score 0):

Людмила - всё-таки имя, существовавшее задолго до Пушкина и Жуковского. См., напр. 
https://slovari.yandex.ru/~книги/Брокгауз%20и%20Ефрон/Людмила/?ncrnd=5805
Комментарий отчего-то не добавляется, допишу здесь.

Порывшись собакой, нашёл ещё версию по Фарлафу: искажённое греческое Харламп (радостный свет)

Comment: Куда именно смотреть? И почему яндекс-словари стали чем-то авторитетным?

Comment: Людмила
блаженная, супруга христианского кн. Чехии
Боривого, бабка св. кн. Вячеслава (Вацлава,
см.), жила после смерти супруга в Праге,
воспитывая своего внука в духе истинного
христианства. В 927 г. она прияла
мученическую кончину в г. Течине, по
наветам вернувшейся к язычеству невестки
ее Драгомиры. Память Л. празднуется 16
сентября. О ней см. житие кн. Вячеслава
("Московский вестник", 1829), сентябрьскую
Минею Макария и пролог под 16 сентября.
Энциклопедический словарь Ф.А. Брокгауза
и И.А. Ефрона. — С.-Пб.: Брокгауз-Ефрон
1890—1907

Comment: Св. Людмила канонизирована  в 1143 году, до раскола Церкви на Православную и Католическую, и чтится до сих пор обеими христианскими конфессиями. Имя, таким образом, изначально не русское, но совершенно точно славянское (чешское). В России становится употребительным после Пушкина.

Comment: Знать бы, как оно писалось... Есть подозрение, что "Людмила" - осовремененный вариант. имя не может быть чешским. Она сербка по рождению.  Насчет раскола - тут сложно... Вы какую дату берете за точку отсчета. Впрочем, вообще не понимаю, какое это имеет отношение... До или после...

Comment: Чехи дают два написания - Ludmila и Lidmila. Второе указывают в скобках. Чем вызвано, не знаю, разбирать по-чешски не силён.

Дату канонизации указал для вящей достоверности, есть люди, для которых если источник православный, то уже подозрительно, не фальшивка ли.

Comment: Раскол - 1054 г. Самая поздняя из возможных дат, изгнание папских легатов из Константинополя. Это так, для справки.

Comment: @mueller, а это как раз важно. Такое различие в написнии свидетельствует, что имя прошло через греческий, где писалось через ипсилон (юпсилон) - т.е. "игрек", передающий звук средний между У и И. А этот факт в свою очередь ставит под сомнение исконно славянское  происхождение.

Comment: Прохождение через греческий может быть разным. Если вы имеете в виду, что именем Людмила  называли девочек византийцы, то этому нет подтверждений. Если же под прохождением через греческий подразумевать то обстоятельство, что имя было впервые записано по-гречески, то, учитывая историю чешской письменности, это вполне вероятно, но о славянском или неславянском происхождении имени ничего не говорит. В самом деле, дата смерти св. Людмилы (927 г.) не столь уж далека от начала моравской миссии Кирилла и Мефодия (863 г.), а поскольку латинский период развития чешской письменности считают с конца

Comment: XI века

(http://feb-web.ru/feb/ivl/vl2/vl2-3933.htm), 

то отмеченная двойственность латинского написания может свидетельствовать и о "прохождении через старославянский" с его юсами, будь то кириллица или глаголица. Так что если это единственный аргумент за "псевдославянскость",  то данное предположение не назовешь основательным. Если же есть ещё, то огласите весь список, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Меня всегда интересовал вопрос, зачем Пушкин поменял местами Ратмира и Руслана. Ратмир - имя явно славянское, с понятным значением. Может быть, в этом причина? Идиосинкразия к сочетанию типа "Божидар Яичница" в применении к понятию "хазарский хан"? Руслан - имя типично тюркское. "Лан" означает "юноша". Например, Темирлан - железный юноша, Нурлан - светлый юноша, Ерлан - юноша-герой, Руслан - юноша-лев/барс.

Comment: 1. Руслан - имя не тюркское, не может быть тюркским. Руслан, Беслан, Сослан, просто Алан - имена **осетинские**. Можно спорить, заимствован ли славянский вариант имени от них или это случайное созвучие, но уж тюрки точно тут не при делах. 2. Кто там чего поменял у Руслана с Ратмиром, осветите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Дополнение к ответу @Матвей Дёмин.  У меня недостаточный рейтинг для комментариев.  Юноша-лев это Арслан, а вот Руслан вполне может быть сокращением от "орусча лан", иначе русский юноша.  Так что несмотря на тюрксое происхождение имени, конечный результат очень даже русский.

Сокращения в именах бывают.  Владимир - владыка мира

Comment: В именах не бывает сокращений.

Answer (score 0):

этимология имени Руслан вовсе не так однозначна. Возможны параллели с Роландом, которое восходит к германскому Hrodland- славная земля (hrod- слава). Возможно 
 аналогичное значение Рус (русский) + лан (в значении земля встречается в диалектах). Ратмир- от основы Рат- войско (ср. Ратник- воин), и мир (известный), те -целом нечто вроде "известный воин". По поводу имени Рогдай, которое встречается в Новгородской летописи, оно явно славянско-балтское по этимологии, по аналогии Рогволод, Рогнеда- имена имеющие параллели в литовском, Рагвалдис и Раганита соответственно. Основа "Рог" в славянских и балтских языках означает "Высокий" (например рог в некоторых диалектах русского означает мыс). Те Рогволод- высокий, высший правитель.С именем Рогнеда посложнее, на прусском языке, например, Раганита означает "маленькая волшебница". Ранней формой имени Рогдай было скорее всего  Рогдар ( распространенный в славянских языках процесс перехода конечных -ар в -ай -ой ,например ратарь (воин, землепашец) - ратай, вар,вор (воин)- в вой)/

Comment: Как этот кирпич на прусском языке читать?

Answer (score 0):

это класическая зашифрованая история. Владимир - Бог, Руслан - Руский Юноша- Руские правители или династия, Людмила - народ, Ратмир - Воинствующий Рим, претиндует на земли  руского народа,Рогдар -Рог -царь, де ар - земли. претендует на народ(Людмилу). Фарлав - лав -закон, фар в данном контексте выступает как анти, получаем беззаконие, Черномор - Чёрная смерть или чёрный мор — вторая в истории пандемия чумы, пик которой пришёлся на 1346—1353 годы. Указывает нам как на дату когда Рим захватил Руские земли и народ. так и на инструмент, с помощью которого был осуществлен захват. Что же нам хотел сказать Пушкин? В 1346 году Рим прибегнув к беззаконию по отношению к Руским правителям и нашим предкам, с помощью пандемии чумы захватил земли а над руским народом  поставил своих царей. Это сказание напоминает историю про Петра 1.

Comment: Скажите, а Пушкин точно знал, что его история зашифрована? Да еще именно этим свеобразным "шифром"?

Comment: а вы что буквально воспринимаете сказки пушкина. тогда вам еще в детский садик нужно ходить

Comment: это сказание принадлежит не пушкину,пушкин лишь изящно его преподнес.

Comment: Не будем переходить на личности. Пожалуйста, объясните, каким образом у Пушкина могли появиться подобные "конспирологические" мотивы. И есть ли какие-то филологические подтверждения вашей версии расшифровки.

Comment: *это сказание принадлежит не пушкину,пушкин лишь изящно его преподнес* - дайте, пожалуста, ссылку на источник этого утверждения.

Answer (score 0):

Разбавлю многочисленные версии несколькими авторитетными ссылками.

Проще всего с **Фарлафом**. Известный литературовед-пушкинист А. Л. Слонимский считал, что происхождение этого имени [не вызывает сомнений](http://feb-web.ru/feb/pushkin/serial/v37/v372183-.htm):

> Эта историческая тенденция сказывается и в подборе имен действующих
> лиц у Пушкина. В частности, имя Фарлафа **НЕСОМНЕННО** (выделено мной — **grizzly**; см. комментарий к ответу behemothus'а) заимствовано из
> договора Олега с греками (911 г.), помещенного в летописи Нестора. В
> числе послов Олега двое носят имена, сходные с именем пушкинского
> героя: Фарлов и Флелаф. Из этих двух имен, по-видимому, и составлено
> имя „Фарлаф“. Так как история Карамзина, где напечатан этот договор
> (т. I, гл. V), вышла только в 1818 г., а Фарлаф у Пушкина фигурирует
> уже в первой песне, написанной раньше, то следует предположить, что
> имя Фарлафа взято непосредственно из летописи.

См. также комментарии к этому абзацу по ссылке. Заодно упомяну (раз уж обсуждалось выше), что:

> ...Никакой принципиальной разницы между „Русланом и Людмилой“ и пушкинскими „простонародными“ сказками, в сущности, нет: и здесь и там мы имеем дело с книжными источниками, обработанными в народном духе [*тем самым опровергается версия о якобы влиянии русской народной поэзии* — **grizzly**].

По поводу Людмилы процитирую известного лингвиста и ономаста В.А. Никонова:

> **Людмила**. Старинное славянское — "милая людям". В "святцы" проникло как имя чешской княгини (922 г.), но признано у русских не было до XX века.

Далее цитирую [работу](http://feb-web.ru/feb/pushkin/serial/is1/is1-216-.htm) пушкиниста Л.Н. Назаровой.

> Отметим, что действие поэмы «Руслан и Людмила» начинается и оканчивается в Киеве, как и в плане неосуществленной поэмы Жуковского. В обоих произведениях героями являются князь Владимир и его богатыри, среди которых находится **Рогдай** (имя его взято и Пушкиным и Жуковским, очевидно, из «Истории Государства Российского» Карамзина).

Плюс комментарий к этому абзацу:

> Интересно, что в черновиках «Руслана и Людмилы»
> герой носит имя «**Рохдая**», почти как у Карамзина (у Карамзина "Рахдай" — **grizzly**).

Споры по этому имени ходили ещё в позапрошлом веке, и мне не удалось найти какое-то окончательное решение. В приведенном ниже источнике имя употребляется в обеих формах (Рохдай и Рогдай) безотносительно к поэме А.С. Пушкина. (Эта журнальная полемика не может иметь доказательной силы, но показывает, что вопрос не имеет тривиального решения.)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По поводу имени **Руслан**: все специалисты по ономастике единодушны в том, что это имя имеет тюркские корни. Здесь можно сослаться на того же В.А. Никонова, или вот ещё, для разнообразия, монография по этимологии осетинских имен и фамилий, где это имя действительно распространено.

**Upd**.
К сожалению, не могу дать рабочую ссылку на осетинскую монографию — при открытии / скачивании файла создаётся только временная ссылка. Автор монографии "Этимологии осетинских имен и фамилий" Таказов Федар Магометович (гуглится).

**Дополнение по поводу имени Руслан**.
Процитирую для примера словарь Фасмера со ссылками на многих других специалистов (я понимаю, что адептов так называемой "народной этимологии" это не убедит — для них количество, качество и авторитетность источников не имеет значения, но для других пользователей замечу, что тюркское происхождение подчёркивается во всех без исключения словарях по этимологии и ономастике):

> **Русла́н, Ерусла́н** – имя богатыря, героя русск. народн. песен, былин, сказок. Заимств. из тюрк., ср. тур., чагат., уйг., тат. arslan
> "лев", казах. aryslan, чув. arǝslan (Радлов I, 327 и сл.); см. Банг,
> KSz 17, 126; WZKМ 13, 112; Гомбоц 110; UJb. 8, 271; Мелиоранский,
> ИОРЯС 10, 2, 72. Ср. тур. Аlр Arslan – имя сельджукского хана, также
> греч. ᾽Αρσίλας у Менандра Протектора, Frgm. 43 (Мюллер, FНG 4, 245) и
> особенно дунайско-болг. ᾽Οσλάν(ν)ας ὁ βαγατούρ (см. на слон).

Comment: Не могу по ссылке пройти. В двух словах, если не трудно, автор вообще знает, что осетины - ираноязычный народ?

Comment: ПС осетины полагаею, что тюрки могли заимствовать имя и приспособить его к своему аслан - лев. Это очень похоже на правду, просто потому, что у осетин есть героиэпосов рустам и Сослан, а также многочислекнные Бесланы, Асраны, Насраны и проч.

Comment: Ссылку исправить не удаётся. Откорректировал ответ. Контакты автора можно найти [в открытом доступе](http://soigsi.com/index.php/struktura/3-otdel-folklora-i-literatury).

Comment: К сожалению, меня совершенно не интересует обсуждение самодельных этимологических версий, которые противоречат мнению всех (без единого исключения) специалистов.

Comment: Спасибо, тно меня не интересуют контакты всех без исключения авторов, который не занют, что осетины - не туркоязычный народ - и не могли заимствовать котойконим "Аланы" от каких-то там тюрок. @grizzly, простите, если вы и далее намерены подобным образом отвечать на любой вопрос по **вашему** тексту, то... ну сами понимаете... )))

Comment: Меня только радует, что каждый, кто обратит внимание на наши споры (здесь или в других темах), сможет без усилий сделать выводы об уровне и релевантности используемых каждой из сторон аргументов :)

Comment: В общем так. Монография в сети действительно упоминается. Ссылок на скачивания или текста нет нигде. Если у вас есть этот текст в любом виде прошу выложить скрин того места, гле бы утверждалось, что осетинское имя "Руслан" или любые другие имена собственные (Беслан, Сослан, Асран, Насран и др.) являются заимствованием из тюркских. Или хотя бы точную цитату.

Comment: *Меня только радует* дэто ваше личное дело. Меня совершенно не радует, что вместо ответа на простейший вопрос в отношении вами сказанного или просьбу пояснить, что собственно вы имели в виду, вы начинаете говорить о каких-то аргументах или пускаетесь в снобизм.... А насчет желающих... Ну разве модератор прочтет. Никому более не интиересно, уверяю вас, читать подобный далекий от научного "спор" ниачом. Да и можно ли это спором назвать, когда одна сторона пускается во все тяжкие только чтобы уйти от ответа на прямой вопрос...

Comment: Спор начинается с того момента, когда обе стороны одинаково понимают предмет спора... А я так и не понял, что вы мне доказываете...